# Sonarqube failed to start DEBUG - Starting WinSW in console mode

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-web, sonarqube-4.5

I install SonarQube using comunity edition: https://www.sonarsource.com/products/sonarqube/downloads/
Unzip it in C:\sonarqube
Try start Server using C:\sonarqube\bin\windows-x86-64\StartSonar.bat
But I saw

```
C:\sonarqube\bin\windows-x86-64>StartSonar.bat
Starting SonarQube...

C:\sonarqube\bin\windows-x86-64>
```

SonarQube doesnt start

Log shows: 2023-06-13 21:54:42,691 DEBUG - Starting WinSW in console mode

Additional info:

I have installed SonarQube version 10

The version of jdk-17

Aproaches which I try:
start cmd as administrator

install another version of SonarQube

I made sure that port 9000 is not busy

I made sure that the paths to jdk in environments had writen well

Answer (score 0):

How do you know SonarQube didn't start?

What do you see in $SQ_HOME/logs folder? Please check what you see in those files and it should give you a hint of what to do next.